# Remove empty sets from a dict inside a list (python 2.7)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, set

So I have some dicts which looks something like this

```
clue={"number":set([i,j]), "var2":x[i]<0.03 or x[j]<0.03, "var3":x[i]>0.97 or x[j]>0.97, "var4":v4}
```

etc.

```
clue={"number":set([k,l]), "var2":x[i]<0.03 or x[j]<0.03, "var3":x[i]>0.97 or x[j]>0.97, "var4":v4}
```

etc.

I created a list of these dictionaries list(clue) because I needed to sort them and join some of the values together, so for example:

```
clue={"number":set([i,j,k,l]), "var2":True, "var3":False, "var4":v4}
```

etc.

```
clue={"number":{}, "var2":True, "var3":False, "var4":v4}
```

etc.

Now because I have a list(clue) the following operation becomes difficult: I want to delete all **dict** entries from my **list(clue)** which have the set {} for number. i.e. The dicts with "number:{}" are worthless (regardless of the other key, values) and are just cluttering up everything else and I want rid of them.

**I would like to make it clear that** I want to get rid of the **whole** dict entry with number:{} rather than **just** the key from that specific dict.

Using Python 2.7

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to delete all dict entries from my list(clue) which have the
>   set {} for number. i.e. The dicts with "number:{}" are worthless
>   (regardless of the other key, values) and are just cluttering up
>   everything else and I want rid of them.

```
filtered_clue = filter(lambda x: len(x['number']), clue)
```